# Creating pojo class and callback for retrofit

Tags: java, retrofit, pojo

Can anyone help with how to create a **pojo** class for the **json** format below with the callback for Retrofit.

I tried http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ but i think its not formated well

Thanks.

```
[
  {
   "trends": [
      {
        "tweet_volume": 3200,
        "events": null,
        "name": "#GanaPuntosSi",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23GanaPuntosSi",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi"
      },
      {
        "tweet_volume": 4200,
        "events": null,
        "name": "#WordsThatDescribeMe",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23WordsThatDescribeMe",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23WordsThatDescribeMe"
     },
      {
        "tweet_volume": 1200,
        "events": null,
        "name": "#10PersonasQueExtra\u00f1oMucho",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%2310PersonasQueExtra%C3%B1oMucho",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot a `]` in your code.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be a bit more specific, like where the closing bracket should go?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Json and I don't know much about it but rekon it's a "key" : "value" pair type language notation akin to python tuples, or java maps, python dictionaries... (and so on). Fro what I can tell your serializer is very buggy so give more details so more qualified people can assist you by helping you fix it so it generates valid JSOn for you.

That being said, I fiddled around with you JSON untill it started working and generated a pojo. you can paste this into jsonschema2pojo and download your class.. hope this helps :) (PS. select Json not JsonSchema radio button)

```
[
  {
    "tweet_volume": 3200,
    "events": null,
    "name": "#GanaPuntosSi",
    "promoted_content": null,
    "query": "%23GanaPuntosSi",
    "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi"
  },
  {
    "tweet_volume": 4200,
    "events": null,
    "name": "#WordsThatDescribeMe",
    "promoted_content": null,
    "query": "%23WordsThatDescribeMe",
    "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23WordsThatDescribeMe"
 },
  {
    "tweet_volume": 1200,
    "events": null,
    "name": "#10PersonasQueExtra\u00f1oMucho",
    "promoted_content": null,
    "query": "%2310PersonasQueExtra%C3%B1oMucho",
    "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?"
  }
]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: No it did not work...i just need a way of creating a pojo class for that kind of son format

Answer (score 0):

It's been long, in case you haven't solved it

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("trends")
@Expose
private List<Trend> trends = null;

public List<Trend> getTrends() {
return trends;
}

public void setTrends(List<Trend> trends) {
this.trends = trends;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Trend.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Trend {

@SerializedName("tweet_volume")
@Expose
private Integer tweetVolume;
@SerializedName("events")
@Expose
private Object events;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("promoted_content")
@Expose
private Object promotedContent;
@SerializedName("query")
@Expose
private String query;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;

public Integer getTweetVolume() {
return tweetVolume;
}

public void setTweetVolume(Integer tweetVolume) {
this.tweetVolume = tweetVolume;
}

public Object getEvents() {
return events;
}

public void setEvents(Object events) {
this.events = events;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Object getPromotedContent() {
return promotedContent;
}

public void setPromotedContent(Object promotedContent) {
this.promotedContent = promotedContent;
}

public String getQuery() {
return query;
}

public void setQuery(String query) {
this.query = query;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

}
```